# how do i get the latest build in jenkns with a specified parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

My goal is to get the latest Jenkins job (jobname hanna) with a specific parameter.

The only reason why I'm doing this is Jenkins do not return a build number when I trigger from my script, so I have to pass in a parameter, but I have to be able to query against that parameter later.

Rigth now I have this, which doesn't return the build ID:

```
curl -X POST 'http://server:8080/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,builds[actions[parameters[name,value]]]]&xpath=/hudson/job[build/action/parameter[name="snapshot"][value="bb"]]&pretty=true'
```

and I get a list of jobs like this:

```
<job><name>hanna</name><build><action><parameter><name>snapshot</name><value>bb</value></parameter></action><action/><action/><action/><action/></build><build><action><parameter><name>snapshot</name><value>bb</value></parameter></action><action/><action/><action/><action/></build><build><action><parameter><name>snapshot</name><value>aa</value></parameter></action><action/><action/><action/><action/><action/></build><build><action/><action/><action/><action/></build></job>⏎
```

which is not exactly what I want, because I want the latest instance of the job hanna with parameter `snapshot=bb`, this return `snap=aa` as well, and also I cannot figure out where the build ID is stored on Jenkins. Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need to use the Jenkins Rest api call to query for a specific build number containing a specific build parameter, use the following query:

```
http://localhost:8080/job/MyJenkinsJob/api/xml?tree=builds[actions[parameters[value]],number]&xpath=//build[action[parameter[value="MyParameterValue"]]]/number
```

This should return something like:

```
<number>49</number>
```

If you would like to know more about XPath filtering, please see some examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**ALTERNATE APPROACH**

To answer your original problem of "the only reason why im doing this is jenkins do not return a build number when i trigger from my script,"

What you could do is run curl with the "-i" parameter.  When you do that, you should see a queue item id # returned.

**For example:**
`curl -X POST -i http//localhost:8080/job/test123/buildWithParameters?aaa=ABC`

**Returns:**
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 03:15:28 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: http://localhost:8080/queue/item/44/
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)

With this queue ID in hand, you can get the build number by going to:
`http://localhost:8080/queue/item/44/api/xml`

Which should return an XML with the  number that you are looking for.

For example:

```
<leftItem>
   ...
   <executable _class="hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild">
      <number>11</number>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/job/test123/11/</url>
    </executable>
</leftItem>
```

Comment: this queue number is very short lived, and i have to keep polling to see if its assigned, if i miss it i have to find another way

Comment: is there anyway of fetching only the latest if there is multiple with the same parameter?

Comment: Yes, I think there probably is a way.  XPath is pretty powerful and contains many functions.  However, this answer has already gotten long (and transgressed even to an alternate approach).  Let's call it a day on this question and start a new one. :)