# how do i get latest build in jenkns with specified parameter

Tags: jenkins

i asked this question [how do i get the latest build in jenkns with a specified parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986194/how-do-i-get-the-latest-build-in-jenkns-with-a-specified-parameter/38987594?noredirect=1#comment65531177_38987594), and the solutions is

```
http://localhost:8080/job/MyJenkinsJob/api/xml?tree=builds[actions[parameters[value]],number]&xpath=//build[action[parameter[value="MyParameterValue"]]]/number&wrapper=list
```

however this would return multiple build numbers, but i only want the latest (one build number only)

```
<list><number>49</number><number>48</number></list>
```

I tried several variation with xpath and it didnt work

Comment: what about building a list (shell/python/or any other ...) and grab the highest build number ?

Comment: i want to find out if the api can do it as well

Answer (score 0):

Does [XPath: Select first element with a specific attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006283/xpath-select-first-element-with-a-specific-attribute) help at all?

So:

```
http://localhost:8080/job/MyJenkinsJob/api/xml?tree=builds[actions[parameters[value]],number]&xpath=(//build[action[parameter[value="MyParameterValue"]]])[0]/number&wrapper=list
```

Or perhaps the brackets need to be elsewhere

Comment: is the return values sorted by default?

Comment: From your example, yes. Perhaps not though, you'll need to test or dig into Jenkins code :) . If you are concerned, processing the XML, like chenchuk says, is probably the best way.